# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

Имеется код

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

driver.get("http://google.com/");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

из этого простого примера получаю ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException    at
>   tera.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:24) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 1 more

pom

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

ОС линукс минт, что не хватает для нормальной работы, гугл не помог, буду признателе за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

замените в pom net.sourceforge.htmlunit на

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, заменил, ошибка осталась Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
 at tera.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Решение наглось, так же удалисть блок с selenium-htmlunit-driver